# How can I get the second line of a string in a clean way?

Tags: java, string

If I have `String c = a + "\n" + b;` given `c` what is the best way to get `b`?
Using `c.substring(c.indexOf("\n") + 1, c.length);` seems error prone and does not take into account any whitespace after `\n`.
I want only `b`

Comment: `c.split("\n")[1].trim()`, assuming that `c` contains `\n` of course ;)

Comment: Have you tried the split method with "\n" as separator? not entirely sure it'll work, but my guess it should.

Comment: If `a` and `b` can contain newlines themselves, there is no reliable way to do this. If not, your method should work well. I don't understand the whitespace remark.

Comment: Should this work in a plattform independant manner? If yes, use `System.getProperty("line.separator")`. If you don't know the source you need a regex: `\\r?\\n`. With Java 8 you can use `\\R`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
c.substring(c.indexOf("\n") + 1).trim();
```

Answer (score 8):

you can use `split` method like this: `c.split("\n")[1]`

Answer (score 2):

Use `c.split("\n")[1]` to get the second part of the string. [0]th element of the array will be `a`, in case you need it as well.

Answer (score 1):

Considering you don't need white spaces.

```
String a = "xyz ";
String b = "    bcd";
String c = a + "\n" + b;
System.out.println(c.substring(c.indexOf("\n") + 1).replaceFirst("\\s++", ""));

Output: 
bcd
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `replaceAll` assuming `a` and `b` variables won't contain any newline characters.

```
System.out.println(str.replaceAll(".*\\n", ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
String formula_regex= "\\n";
line = c.split(formula_regex);

System.out.println(line)
```